# ETA prediction research

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I found an ETA prediction project on Github describing ferries in Washington state[Ferry ETA Prediction](https://github.com/mtduman/Ferry_ETA_Prediction). The raw data used for this project has been collected from WSDOT web site (at a resolution of 1 minute), and between January 1, 2017 to March 17, 2017. It is in JavaScript Object Notation (JSON) format. The author gives a link to the original data (https://www.wsdot.com/ferries/vesselwatch/Vessels.ashx), but I can't retrieve raw data for the past few months, for instance the raw data between March to June 2021. What do I need to do?(like use the library of requests(python)?or something?)
[image: WSDOT]

Answer (score 0):

`requests` is a bit slow from my experience because most of the code written with it is synchronous and therefore a lot of blocking code is involved. Try setting up an async HTTP client that sends requests to `https://www.wsdot.com/ferries/vesselwatch/Vessels.ashx` , you should check out AIOHTTP https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/, I've used this to **scrape** I think 100+ pages in less than a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You might have more luck with the history page:

https://www.wsdot.com/ferries/vesselwatch/VesselWatchHis.aspx

Otherwise I think you're out of luck.  From a quick glance it seems that link you provided gives only *current* state; they don't seem to have an api for getting past state.  Hence the need to sample it, *because* only current data is available (if you're on linux, try running `curl that_URL | grep datetime`, or if you have `jq`, `curl that_URL | jq | grep datetime`).

For getting the current data you can use requests, or indeed newer libraries as mentioned in the other answer.

Comment: Yes, this https://www.wsdot.com/ferries/vesselwatch/Vessels.ashx is dynamically refreshed, so when I open up Google Developer Tools, You can see the current url for .../vesselwatch/Vessels.ashx?dojo.preventCache=1632626526859, I tried to replace the time of interest with a timestamp in preventCache, but I failed